# jQuery automatic vertical scroll if viewport too small

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've made a HTML-based information screen, which is shown full screen. I use several jQuery script to animate the screen, e.g. I loop trough a list of `<article>` tags which are shown one by one on the screen. The problem is that some of these "articles" are too long for the screen. So ideally, I want to detect when these articles are too long (best trigger might be if a vertical scrollbar becomes visible) and I want the text to scroll automatically downwards in a specified period in this case.

I've seen several scrolling and slideshow plugins which show some of this functionality but not all. Do you know a (jQuery) plugin with which I can easily achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

To detect when a scrollbar is visible with jQuery, you can use this snippet: `var hasVerticalScrollbar = element.scrollHeight>element.clientHeight;` it will return true or false depending on whether or not a scrollbar is visible.

Then, you can use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to check the result of the variable and if it's value is true then use jQuery's [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) function to scroll downwards.